# Clarify on Mumford's Red Book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm reading Mumford's book, precisely I'm looking at *Proposition 1*, page 28. In the image below I included the definition too, because it is necessary to give a sense to the proposition. Now, basically I don't understand what is $R_f $: is it a notation for $R_{(f)} $, where $(f) $ is the ideal generated by $f ?$ Moreover, I was convinced that $o_X (U) $ consisted of the functions $\frac f g$, with $f,g\in R $ and $g $ never vanishing on $U $; however it turns out that it is not true, and that the *Proposition 1* is involved. So can you make clear to me what does the proposition mean? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: $R_f$ is the localization $S^{-1}R$ where $S=\{1,f,f^2,f^3,\cdots\}$. Proposition 1 identifies the value of the sheaf $\underline{o}_X$ on the open set $X_f$ as $R_f$. Without more context about what you previously thought, why you thought it, and why you now believe it's wrong, it will be hard to address those issues - if you want more help with that, please expand the question.

Comment: @KReiser I was convinced that every element of $o_X (U) $ was a function of the type $\frac f g $ (with $f,g \in R $ and $g $ never vanishing on $U $). I believed that because if a sheaf $o_x $ contains the functions $\frac f g $ (with $g $ non vanishing in $x $), shouldn't the elements in the intersection of  the $o_x $ (for all $x\in U $) be the functions $\frac f g $, with $g $ non vanishing on all $U ?$

Comment: I don't understand why is not true what I said in the comment above and how the proposition is involved in this. Thanks

Comment: Why do you believe this is not true? Did someone tell you this? Did you read this somewhere? Have you convinced yourself of this via some example? By providing more details, it will be easier for an answer to address your specific concerns.

Comment: I believe that this isn't true because one page later Mumford says: "if $h $ is in $o_X (U) $ for some open $U\subset X $, then it need not be true that $h=\frac f g $, with $f,g $ in $R $ and $g $ vanishing nowhere in $U $. The *Proposition 1*  shows that this is true however if $U $ has the form $X_g $". I don't understand why it isn't always true (Mumford makes an example involving projective spaces but I'm not practical with them). I cannot give more details because I started to study algebraic geometry a few days ago, so I cannot make great reasonings. Thanks for the disposablity @KReiser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{uo}[]{\underline{o}}$

As discussed in the comments: $R_f$ is the localization $S^{-1}R$ with $S=\{1,f,f^2,f^3,\cdots\}$. Proposition 1 identifies the value of the sheaf $\uo_X$ on the open set $X_f$ to be $R_f$.

Let's try to work through your confusion about the value of $\underline{o}_X$ on open subsets not of the form $X_f$. On the one hand, if we have an irreducible variety $X$ with affine coordinate ring $R$ and structure sheaf $\uo_X$, then as Mumford notes, the rings $\uo_X(U)$ for every open set $U\subset X$ and every stalk $\uo_{X,x}$ inject in to $K=\operatorname{Frac} R$, so we can view elements of $\uo_X(U)$ or $\uo_{X,x}$ as elements of $K$. The problem comes when we try to understand what equality means for these images in $K$ - it's more subtle than "they're the same map $U\to k$".

Let us attempt to understand when two elements are equal in $K$. Suppose $\frac{f_1}{g_1}=\frac{f_2}{g_2}$ with $f_i,g_i\in R$. By the definition of the fraction field of an integral domain, these are the same iff $f_1g_2=f_2g_1$, which corresponds to the two functions agreeing on $D(g_1g_2)$. In particular, equality means that there's an open set on which the two functions eventually restrict to be equal on.

So it may happen that there are functions $F_1=\frac{f_1}{g_1}$ on $X_{g_1}$ and $F_2=\frac{f_2}{g_2}$ on $X_{g_2}$ which are equal on $X_{g_1g_2}$ (and thus equal as elements of $K$) and patch together to form a function on $X_{g_1}\cup X_{g_2}$, but without the formula $\frac{f_1}{g_1}$ or $\frac{f_2}{g_2}$ being valid on the whole of $X_{g_1}\cup X_{g_2}$.

The example Mumford gives is instructive. Let $X=V(xy-zw)\subset k^4$, with $R=k[x,y,z,w]/(xy-zw)$. As $xy-zw$ is irreducible, we have that $X$ is an irreducible algebraic set, with fraction field $K=\operatorname{Frac} R$. Now consider the two formulas $\frac{x}{w}$ and $\frac{z}{y}$. The first defines a function on $X_w$, and the second defines a function on $X_y$. These are equal on the overlap $X_{wy}$, as $\frac xw=\frac zy$ there, so they glue to a function on $X_{w}\cup X_y$ and they're also equal as elements of $K$. But there is no one formula in $K$ that will define this function on $X_w\cup X_y$: a specific formula $f/g$ will always be defined on $X$ away from $V(g)$, and $V(g)\subset X$ is either empty, codimension one, or the whole space (for irreducible affine $X$). By contrast, the function on $X_{w}\cup X_{y}$ is defined on the complement of a set of codimension two, and there's no way to extend the function over this. So there is no one choice of a formula for the function we constructed which can be valid on the whole of $X_w\cup X_y$.

So what has happened here? The format we've chosen to write down representatives of our functions has failed us, because the version of equality we have inside $K$ isn't the same as what we need to write down functions in general. What might be better said here is that $\uo_X(U)=\cap_{x\in U} \uo_x$ gives us representatives of functions that can be extended to the whole of $U$, not that the elements of $\uo_X(U)$ necessarily define functions which are valid on the whole of $U$. Proposition 1 tells us that these two concepts are actually the same when $U$ is the nonvanishing set of a regular function $f$ on $X$.