# Clarify on a proof of Mumford's Red Book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm looking at the proof of the proposition below; I don't understand why we can say that $F\in o_x $, then $F=\frac h g $, with  $g,h\in R, g (x)\ne 0 $, on all $X_f $ (this is the implication marked in yellow). I mean, shouldn't this be true only in an open containing $x $? It seems to me that we are using what we want to prove, but of course I must be missing something. Thanks in advance for the help

[image]

Comment: I don't follow the notation completely, but I think you are looking at two different objects, $O_X(U)$, where $U$ is an open subset of $X$ and $O_x$, where $x \in X$ is a point. It seems like the book already defined the stalk $O_x$ and using it to show the statement.

Comment: Yes @Youngsu that's what I'm saying; if we are talking about the stalk  $O_x $ at the point $x $, then how do we conclude that $F $ is equal to $\frac h g $ globally? We can just say that $F=\frac h g $ near $x $

Comment: How does he define $O_X(U)$ for an open subset $U$ of $X$?

Comment: This is Mumford's Red Book; $O_X (U) $ is defined as $\bigcap _ {x\in U} O_x$

Comment: Hi. I believe that he does it two steps. Maybe it is worth reorganizing his proof. 

We want $f^n \in B$. This condition is equivalent to that $V(B) \subset V(f) := \{ x \in X \mid f(x) = 0 \}$. In other words, it suffices to show that if $x \not\in V(f)$, then $x \not\in V(B)$. 
This is achieved by the local equation $F = h/g \in O_x$ for any $x \in X_f = X - V(f)$. Since such $g$ is in $B$ and $g(x) \neq 0$, $x \not\in V(B)$.

Comment: @Youngsu thanks for the disposability. What you wrote is clear, my problem is still this: why can we say that "such $g $ is in $B $"? The relation $F=\frac h g $ holds only near $x $; proving that this is true for every $x\in X_f $ doesn't imply that there is a $g $ such that $gF\in R $ on all $X_f $.

Comment: Actually, this implication seems to me the implication that we want to prove with the Proposition itself; even though I know I must be wrong, I really can't find the mistake

Comment: $F = h/g$ holds only near $x$ means $h,g \in R$ and $g(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't mean that $gF\in R $ on all $X_f $, i.e. it doesn't mean that $g\in B $

Comment: Why not? ......

Comment: Because far from $x$ we can have that $F=\frac {h'} {g'}$, with $h',g' \in R$ different from $h,g$. So $gF\in R$ only near $x$, since $g\frac {h'} {g'}\notin R$

Comment: Having the representation of $F$ as $h'/g'$ or $h/g$ depends on $x \in X$. However once one has $F = h/g$, where $h, g \in R$ so that $F$ is in the field of fractions of $R$, whether or not $g$ belongs to $B$, which is an $R$-ideal, does not refer to $x$ anymore.

Comment: In order to be in $B $, a polynomial $g $ must satisfy $gF \in R$ for every $x\in X_f $; if $F $ has different representations in $X_f $, the fact that $gF \in R$ near $x $ doesn't imply that $gF \in R$ on all $X_f $, i.e.  $g\notin B $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like Mumford's notation, so I'm going to replace it with what I like. Briefly, I use $\mathcal{O}_X$ for the structure sheaf (Mumford uses $\underline{o}_X$), and $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for the stalk at $x$ (Mumford uses $\underline{o}_x$).

Let's recall some definitions from earlier on this page. For an irreducible algebraic set $X\subset k^n$ with coordinate ring the integral domain $R$, Mumford defines $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=R_{m_x}=\{f/g\mid f,g\in R, g(x)\neq 0\}$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(U) = \bigcap_{x\in U} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, where the intersection is taken inside $K=\operatorname{Frac} R$, the fraction field of $R$.

The yellow highlighted claim is just an application of these definition: $X_f$ is nonempty (*), so there's some point $x$ in it. Then as $F\in \mathcal{O}_X(X_f)$, it must be in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, and by the definition, we can write it as $F=h/g$ with $g(x)\neq 0$. For any other representation $F=h'/g'$ at any other point in $X_f$, we get that $\frac{h'}{g'}=\frac{h}{g}$ as elements of $K$ because they agree on the nonempty open subset which is the complement of $V(g)\cup V(g')$ by [a previous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577920/clarify-on-mumfords-red-book/3580359#3580359) on this subject. So we have that for *any* representation of $F$, $gF\in R$, and we may proceed in the proof.

(*) if $X_f$ is empty then $f=0$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(X_f)=\mathcal{O}_X(\emptyset)=0=R_0$, so we needn't worry about this.

---

What's probably going on here is that you are familiar with  (or at least have heard of) another definition/construction of the structure sheaf. In such an alternate construction, you would be correct that two functions having equal images in the stalk does in fact just mean that there's some open neighborhood of that point where they agree. On the other hand, this isn't how Mumford works in this text, so that intuition is not applicable to understanding this proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but I still can't convince me of that. Read the remark IV, at page 29; how does it reconcile with your definition? I mean, in my ideas, they reconcile because a function in $\mathcal O_ {X,x} \cap \mathcal O_ {X,y} $, can be represented in different ways in $x $ and in $y $, but these ways are in the same class of equivalence. However with this point of view, one couldn't say that  $F\in \mathcal O_ {X,x}$ implies that $F=\frac h g $, with $h,g $ fixed on all $X_f $, by definition; for, in another point, we could have $F=\frac {h+r} {g+t} $, with $r,t \in (f)$.

Comment: @Dorian Writing $F=\frac{h+r}{g+t}$ is no matter: these two representations agree on the nonempty open set which is the complement of $V(g)\cup V(g+t)$, which means that $\frac{h}{g}=\frac{h+r}{g+t}$ inside $K$, as detailed in [our previous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577920/clarify-on-mumfords-red-book/3580359#3580359). So if $gF\in R$ using one representation, any other representation must also be in $R$.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I read again your answer to that old question and now things are clearer. Basically the "problem" in that remark IV is that $w $ and $y $ are not equal in $R $, even if $\frac x y$ and $\frac z w$ are equal in $K $, and this is what the proposition excludes, right?